# Issue with laravel eloquent model property

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I'm trying to print {{$day->date}} in a view. Instead of full date *YYYY-MM-DD* the property only returns year *YYYY*.

Can anyone explain me why it is working like this ? & how to get full date from the property ?

The **Code**

```
@foreach($calendar as $day)
    {{dd($day->date)}}
    <br>
@endforeach
```

**Expected output**

```
2022-03-01
2022-03-02
...
...
```

**Actual output**

```
2022
2022
...
...
```

Attributes of `$day` in a view : using `{{dd($day)}}` blade

```
#attributes: array:4 [▼
    "date" => "2022-03-01"
    "day" => "Tuesday"
    "note" => "Public Holiday - Maha Sivarathri"
    "is_working_day" => 0
  ]
```

output of `{{dd($day->date)}}` in a view

```
2022
```

The **Controller**

```
$calendar = Calendar::wherebetween('date',[$date_from,$date_to])->get();
$data['calendar']=$calendar;
return view('cms.advanceprogram.calendar')->with($data);
```

The **Calendar.php** Model

```
class Calendar extends Model{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $primaryKey = 'date';

    public function advanceprograms(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(AdvanceProgram::class, 'advance_program_calendar', 'date', 'advance_program_id');
    }
}
```

The **Migration**

```
Schema::create('calendars', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->date('date')->primary();
    $table->string('day');
    $table->string('note')->nullable();
    $table->boolean('is_working_day');
});
```

Comment: As far as I can remember Laravel makes the date attribute to Carbon object. So this should work. Try `$day->date->format('Y-m-d');`

Comment: The **format** method not defined in **Caledar** model. it gives me an error.
```Call to undefined method App\Models\Calendar::format() ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you shouldn't use date as primary key. Add column `id` for primary key.

Laravel cast primary key as integer. Replace or remove `protected $primaryKey` in model and you will get correctly result in Blade.

Model `Calendar`

```php
class Calendar extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function advanceprograms(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(AdvanceProgram::class, 'advance_program_calendar', 'date', 'advance_program_id');
    }
}
```

View

```
@foreach($calendar as $day)
    {{$day->date}}
    <br>
@endforeach
```

Result:

```
2022-03-01
```

**OR**

Add to `Calendar` a line `protected $keyType = 'string';`

Like this:

```
class Calendar extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $primaryKey = 'date';
    protected $keyType = 'string';

    public function advanceprograms(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(AdvanceProgram::class, 'advance_program_calendar', 'date', 'advance_program_id');
    }
}
```

**OR**

Add to `Calendar` a line `protected $keyType = 'date';`
Then field `date` will be instance of a `Carbon` class.
Like this:

```
class Calendar extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $primaryKey = 'date';
    protected $keyType = 'date';

    public function advanceprograms(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(AdvanceProgram::class, 'advance_program_calendar', 'date', 'advance_program_id');
    }
}
```

Then you may use Carbon methods in view. Like this:

```
@foreach($calendar as $day)
    {{$day->date->format('d-m-Y')}}
    <br>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Your solution ```protected $keyType = 'string';```solved the issue;

Answer (score 1):

**You can try this**

```
protected $primaryKey = 'date';
public $incrementing = false;   // no auto increment
public $timestamps = false;     // if there are not timestamp table
```

> I think it's work